# Show image created by imagejpeg

Tags: php, image, gd

I create an image with an external function.

The function that returns the raw data of the image:

```
function create_image()
{
    ...
    ImageJPEG($myimg,NULL,85);
    $imgdata = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean();          
    return $imgdata;
}
```

My script which should show what the image looks like:

```
$rawdata = create_image();
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,".base64_encode($rawdata)."" />
```

Now the image is not complete in the `<img>` tag. If I make the quality 50 (with `ImageJPEG($myimg,NULL,50);`) the image will be displayed completely. If I catch the rawdata and write it to the disk, the image will be complete in every quality.

```
$rawdata = create_image();
$im = imagecreatefromstring($rawdata);
ImageJPEG($im,"./test.jpg",90);
```

Only in the `<img>` tag it doesn't work.

Does anybody have an idea why it doesn't work?

Comment: How are you outputting the image to an "img-tag"? As data URL?

Comment: No, i post the rawdata in the img-tag like shown above

Comment: Well... that *is* a data URL. :)

Comment: ok, sorry i didnt know that. i thought you mean an url to an image :-)

Comment: Note that this is a very inefficient method of outputting images, and it won't work in older versions of Internet Explorer. It would be much preferable to create the image in a separate image resource.

Comment: ok, what do you mena with separate ressource ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally have never used this technique, I usually use a simple image tag with my image.jpg.php (for example) as an image. For this I put a `header("Content-type: image/jpeg")` in the image file and simply echo the data.

I really never have tried it with raw data, but I believe this would be preferrable, especially for maintenance (and compatibility).